org mode publish to html how to deal with relative links to file like images?
I want to publish notes I have. On those org notes I have linked images [[file:./image.png]] with the .png files adjacent to the .org files.
Now I want to publish all of that with to HTML. The export works great, the only issue is with the relative link to images. Indeed, when publishing, it puts assets into a separate folder, when on my notes it is in the same folder as it is easier (or maybe you know a better workflow to include images easily into org notes, but that’s out of the scope of the question ---though happy to read you).
Here is what my structure looks like:
.
├── notes
│   ├── file.org
│   └── image.png
└── other_notes
    ├── other_file.org
    └── other_image.png

And this is what org-publish does:
.
├── notes
│   ├── file.org
│   └── image.png
├── other_notes
│   ├── other_file.org
│   └── other_image.png
└── public
    ├── assets
    │   ├── image.png
    │   └── other_impage.png
    ├── file.html
    └── other_file.html

But in the HTML, org doesn’t change the link to the image hence having: <img src="./image.png">, which of course does not exist.
Is there any way to overcome this or to dynamically change links based on where assets are put?
Here is my build-site.el script:
;; Load the publishing system
(require 'org)
(require 'ox-publish)
(require 'ox-html)

;; Necessary for code blocks
(require 'package)
(setq package-user-dir (expand-file-name "./.packages"))
(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

;; Initialize the package system
(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))


;; Install dependencies
(package-install 'htmlize)


;; Customize the HTML output
(setq org-html-validation-link nil            ; Don't show validation link
      org-html-head-include-scripts nil       ; Use own scripts
      org-html-head-include-default-style nil ; Use own styles
      org-publish-use-timestamps-flag nil ; Don’t use timestamps
      org-publish-cache nil
      ;;      org-publish-timestamp-directory "org-timestamps/"
      org-html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdn.simplecss.org/simple.min.css\">"
      org-html-doctype "html5"
      org-html-html5-fancy t
      org-export-with-smart-quotes t
      )


;; Define the publishing project
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
        ("notes"
         :base-directory "./../"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "./public"
     :exclude "./"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
         :org-html-preamble nil
     :with-author t           ;; Don't include author name
         :with-creator t            ;; Include Emacs and Org versions in footer
         :with-toc t                ;; Include a table of contents
         :section-numbers nil       ;; Don't include section numbers
         :time-stamp-file nil
     :auto-sitemap nil)
        ("static"
         :base-directory "./../"
         :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
         :publishing-directory "./public/assets"
     :exclude "./"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
         :time-stamp-file nil
     :auto-sitemap nil)
        ("cours"
         :components ("notes" "static"))))

(org-publish-all t)
(message "Build complete!")


You need to organize this yourself: org-publish does not help. See the second and third paragraphs in the section Example: complex publishing configuration.
